# How to store count-up timer in JavaScript as users navigate to separate routes in the web-page

Tags: javascript, flask

I am trying to build a web-page that allows you to start a count-up timer when you click the start button and allows you to navigate to different route on the web-page start another timer and the navigate back to the first page and have the timer still running. Currently I have the and button functionality working. However, I am not sure how to get the clock not to reset. when I navigate to another page. This The web-page is mostly written wit Python and Flask, But I am using JavaScript for the time functionality. This is the only JavaScript I have worked with and most of it comes from other posts.

```html
<div id=time>
<div><span id="hour"></span>:<span id="minute"></span>:<span id="seconds"></span></div>

<button id="start-btn">Start</button>
<button id="stop-btn">Pause</button>
<button id="reset-btn">Reset</button>
      
</div>
<script>
  let hour = 0;
  let minute = 0;
  let seconds = 0;
  let totalSeconds = 0;
  
  let intervalId = null;
  
  function startTimer() {
    ++totalSeconds;
    hour = Math.floor(totalSeconds /3600);
    minute = Math.floor((totalSeconds - hour*3600)/60);
    seconds = totalSeconds - (hour*3600 + minute*60);

    document.getElementById("hour").innerHTML =hour;
    document.getElementById("minute").innerHTML =minute;
    document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML =seconds;
  }

  document.getElementById('start-btn').addEventListener('click', () => {
    intervalId = setInterval(startTimer, 1000);
  })
  
  document.getElementById('stop-btn').addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (intervalId)
      clearInterval(intervalId);
  });
  
   
  document.getElementById('reset-btn').addEventListener('click', () => {
     totalSeconds = 0;
     document.getElementById("hour").innerHTML = '0';
     document.getElementById("minute").innerHTML = '0';
     document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML = '0';
  });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to prevent that your timer got reseted, use a cookie to store the date when the timer started.

Do not increase your timer every second, but instead subtract the current time with the time when the timer started.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Timer test</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="time">
    <div><span id="hour"></span>:<span id="minute"></span>:<span id="seconds"></span></div>

    <button id="start-btn">Start</button>
    <button id="stop-btn">Pause</button>
    <button id="reset-btn">Reset</button>

    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      let hour = 0;
      let minute = 0;
      let seconds = 0;
      let pauseTime = null;
      let start = [...document.cookie.matchAll(/([^;=]+)=([^;=]+)(;|$)/g)].filter(x => x[1].trim() == 'timer').map(x => Number(x[2].trim()))[0];
      if(start != null) {
         if(start > 0) start = new Date(start);
         else if(start < 0) { 
           pauseTime = -start;
           start = new Date(Date.now() + start); //+- = -
         } else start = null;
      } else start = null;
      let intervalId = null;


      function startTimer() {
        let totalSeconds;
        if(pauseTime) {
           start = new Date(Date.now() - pauseTime);
           totalSeconds = pauseTime;
           return;
        } else {
           totalSeconds = Math.floor((Date.now() - start.getTime()) / 1000);
        }
        hour = Math.floor(totalSeconds /3600);
        minute = Math.floor((totalSeconds - hour*3600)/60);
        seconds = totalSeconds - (hour*3600 + minute*60);

        document.getElementById("hour").innerHTML =hour;
        document.getElementById("minute").innerHTML =minute;
        document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML =seconds;
      }
      if(start) intervalId = setInterval(startTimer, 1000);

      document.getElementById('start-btn').addEventListener('click', () => {
         if(pauseTime) {
            pauseTime = null;
         } else {
           if(start) return;
           start = new Date();
           intervalId = setInterval(startTimer, 1000);
         }
         document.cookie = "timer=" + String(start.getTime());
      })

      document.getElementById('stop-btn').addEventListener('click', () => {
        pauseTime = Date.now() - start.getTime();
        document.cookie = "timer=" + String(-pauseTime);
      });


      document.getElementById('reset-btn').addEventListener('click', () => {
         start = null;
         document.cookie = "timer=null";
         if(intervalId) clearInterval(intervalId);
         document.getElementById("hour").innerHTML = '0';
         document.getElementById("minute").innerHTML = '0';
         document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML = '0';
      });

      </script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I appreciate you pointing me towards cookies. I thought that may be the way to go. By chance did you get this script to actually show the time?  When I ran the script it mentioned and unexpected token in line line 37. To get around that I took out the mentioned "}" but it again errors out on line 29 with Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getTime' of null. Any idea why?

Comment: Fixed issues, it works now. I cannot make a snippet because the snippet is sandboxed and is not allowed to use cookies.

Comment: This worked well. I do have timers on multiple pages, but I just slightly renamed each "timer" in the cookies and e seemed to work for each page now. Thank you!!!!!!!!